# How to use two IEnumerables in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hello everyone how to pass two or more than IEnumerables lists to view? Here is my action controller:

```
 ServicesClient client = new ServicesClient();
 client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "service_test";
 client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "..";
            client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None;

            ListCity[] city = client.GetCity();
            ListStreet[] street = client.GetStreet(2);

            return View(city);
```

And my View:

```
model IEnumerable<ListCity>

@using icerik.EmlakServices 
@{

    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Test.cshtml";
}


<select>

@foreach(var item in Model)
{

    <option>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.CityName)</option>
}
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a ViewModel in this case. So something like this:

```
public class MyViewModel{
  public ListCity[] City {get;set;}
  public ListStreet[] Street {get;set;}
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
var viewmodel = new MyViewModel{
                  City = client.GetCity(),
                  Street = client.GetStreet(2)
                };
return View(viewModel);
```

Then in your view:

```
model MyViewModel
```

Then you can get the collections in your view like `Model.City`, or `Model.Street`.

For all but the very basic cases, you usually end up creating a ViewModel for almost all your views. So name them properly so you know what they are doing. I called it `MyViewModel` in the example since I don't know the context.

Also, I would name the variables `Cities` and `Streets` since they are collections, and not just single elements.